# How to shuffle a pandas GroupBy object?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that contains image names and several columns containing features, the image can contain several rows with the same image name but with different column values.

Here's how the DataFrame might look like:

```
        image  val1  val2  val3
0  image1.png    12    14    15
1  image1.png    10    15    10
2  image2.png    12    -3     7
3  image2.png    17    21     1
4  image6.png    12    12     2
5  image6.png   112    12    10
```

Then I need to group images by image name, so I use `groupby()`:

```
groups = df.groupby('image')
```

Then I need to split the data into train and validation sets, so I do the following:

```
groups = groups.apply(np.array)
training_set = groups[:separation_index]
valid_set = groups[separation_index:]
```

The problem is I need to shuffle the data(the groups) first before splitting.

I tried `np.random.shuffle(groups)` but it does not work, does not produce any errors however it doesn't work, the data keeps the same order.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this without grouping, instead getting the unique group names (images) as a list, randomly selecting the train images from that list, and then indexing the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [
        {"image": "image1.png", "val1": 12, "val2": 14, "val3": 15},
        {"image": "image1.png", "val1": 10, "val2": 15, "val3": 10},
        {"image": "image2.png", "val1": 12, "val2": -3, "val3": 7},
        {"image": "image2.png", "val1": 17, "val2": 21, "val3": 1},
        {"image": "image6.png", "val1": 12, "val2": 12, "val3": 2},
        {"image": "image6.png", "val1": 112, "val2": 12, "val3": 10},
    ]
)

images = df["image"].unique()
train_images = np.random.choice(images, size=2, replace=False)

train_idxs = df["image"].isin(train_images)
train_df = df[train_idxs]
test_df = df[~train_idxs]

print(train_df)
print()
print(test_df)

        image  val1  val2  val3
0  image1.png    12    14    15
1  image1.png    10    15    10
4  image6.png    12    12     2
5  image6.png   112    12    10

        image  val1  val2  val3
2  image2.png    12    -3     7
3  image2.png    17    21     1
```

Comment: This was exactly what I did once I encounter the same problem. Only that I used `train_images = np.random.choice(images, replace=False)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yeah that's better

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle the data in pandas itself:

```
groups = df.groupby('image')
grouped_df = groups.aggregate(np.sum)
# random order for all rows 
grouped_df = grouped_df.sample(frac=1)
```

Result:

```
In [103]: grouped_df
Out[103]:
            val1  val2  val3
image                       
image2.png    29    18     8
image6.png   124    24    12
image1.png    22    29    25
```

Which you can then index into:

```
grouped_df[:separation_index]
grouped_df[separation_index:]
```